# Memory leak double pointer

Tags: c, malloc, free, valgrind

I can't figure out what I've done wrong here. New to valgrind and C in general but have managed to clean up all my mem leaks except this one

```
==8749== HEAP SUMMARY:
==8749==     in use at exit: 880 bytes in 11 blocks
==8749==   total heap usage: 80 allocs, 69 frees, 5,620 bytes allocated
==8749== 
==8749== 400 bytes in 5 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1 of 2
==8749==    at 0x4C2A2DB: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==8749==    by 0x402B1C: tokenize (tm_utility.c:78)
==8749==    by 0x402E57: load_data (tm_utility.c:188)
==8749==    by 0x400D0A: main (tm.c:57)
==8749== 
==8749== 480 bytes in 6 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 2 of 2
==8749==    at 0x4C2A2DB: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==8749==    by 0x402B1C: tokenize (tm_utility.c:78)
==8749==    by 0x402C97: load_data (tm_utility.c:147)
==8749==    by 0x400D0A: main (tm.c:57)
==8749==
```

It relates to this function:

```
char** tokenize(const char* input)
{
    char* str = (char*)strdup(input);
    int count = 0;
    int capacity = 10;
    char** result = malloc(capacity*sizeof(*result)); /*LINE 78*/

    char* tok=strtok(str,",");

    while(1)
    {
        if (count >= capacity)
            result = realloc(result, (capacity*=2)*sizeof(*result));

        result[count++] = tok? strdup(tok) : tok;

        if (!tok) break;

        tok=strtok(NULL,",");
    }

    free(str);
    return result;
}
```

I can see that I haven't free'd something there but I cant figure out where to free it (calling function or locally??) and exactly what it is I'm supposed to free?

Help?

Thanks

EDIT:

Here is the code from the calling function. I couldn't figure out what else I need to free, tried a few different things but just made it worse and ended up posting here.

```
while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), coinsfile_stream) != NULL)
{

    tokens = tokenize(line);

    for(i=tokens; i && *i; ++i)
    {

        if(y==0)
        {
            tm->coins[x].denomination = atoi(*i);
            y=1;
            x++;
        }
        else
        {
            tm->coins[z].count = atoi(*i);
            y=0;
            z++;
        }
        free(*i);
    }
}
```

Comment: If there is no `,` in `input` the code returns an invalid reference as first element, as it is assigned `tok`, which had been assigned `str`, and `str` is `free()`ed when leaving `tokenize`.

Comment: @alk true, but all the input does contain a `,`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code that calls `tokenize()` in `load_data()` seems to be responsible for doing the freeing.  You're returning the allocated space to the calling function.

---

With the extra code now shown in the question, you need to add a `free(tokens);` after the `for` loop that processes the tokens.  This code below runs with a clean bill of health from `valgrind`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char **tokenize(const char *input);

char **tokenize(const char *input)
{
    char *str = (char *)strdup(input);
    int count = 0;
    int capacity = 10;
    char **result = malloc(capacity*sizeof(*result)); /*LINE 78*/

    char *tok = strtok(str, ",\n");

    while (1)
    {
        printf("Found: <<%s>>\n", tok);
        if (count >= capacity)
            result = realloc(result, (capacity *= 2)*sizeof(*result));

        result[count++] = tok ? strdup(tok) : tok;

        if (!tok)
            break;

        tok = strtok(NULL, ",\n");
    }

    free(str);
    return result;
}

int main(void)
{
    char line[1024];
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;
    int z = 0;

    struct Coin {
        int denomination;
        int count;
    };
    struct Trade {
        struct Coin coins[10];
    };
    struct Trade tm1;
    struct Trade *tm = &tm1;

    while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), stdin) != NULL)
    {
        char **tokens = tokenize(line);

        for (char **i = tokens; i && *i; ++i)
        {
            printf("Token: <<%s>>\n", *i);
            if (y == 0)
            {
                tm->coins[x].denomination = atoi(*i);
                y = 1;
                x++;
            }
            else
            {
                tm->coins[z].count = atoi(*i);
                y = 0;
                z++;
            }
            free(*i);
        }
        free(tokens);
    }
}
```

Data file:

```
12,23
34,45
56,67
```

Example output:

```
Found: <<12>>
Found: <<23>>
Found: <<(null)>>
Token: <<12>>
Token: <<23>>
Found: <<34>>
Found: <<45>>
Found: <<(null)>>
Token: <<34>>
Token: <<45>>
Found: <<56>>
Found: <<67>>
Found: <<(null)>>
Token: <<56>>
Token: <<67>>
```

Beware: my code relies on the systems I'm working on (Mac OS X 10.9 Mavericks; GCC 4.8.2 — but `valgrind` run in an ancient Linux VM hosted on the same platform) not crashing when asked to print the string pointed at by the null pointer.  You need to review the `while (1)` loop; you should probably just change it to `while (tok != 0)` or equivalent.  Once you've done that, you can then simplify the body of the loop too; there are two now redundant tests for nullness.

Comment: Note that freeing just `result` is not enough. You also have to free all the strings inside `result`, since they come from `strdup`.

Comment: Thanks. I have been trying to free from the calling function but can't get it...question updated.